# Why is the Nonstandard Calculus Limit Equal to the Limit in Standard Real Analysis?

Tags: real-analysis

The definition of a limit in real analysis is as follows: $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)$ is $L_1$ if

$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0, \forall x\neq c$, [ $|x-c|<\delta\implies|f(x)-L_1|<\epsilon$].

In [nonstandard calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonstandard_calculus), we say $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)$ is $L_2$ if 
$x-c$ is infintesimal, then $f(x)-L_2$ is infintesimal.

> When considering these two definitions, why does $L_1=L_2$ hold true?

I thought that this was due to the transfer principle but that goes into other formulas. I am just curious as to why these two objects are equal to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the proof.  This is for any nonstandard model in the sense of Robinson, not just one constructed by ultrafilters.

Let $R$ be the standard real numbers, and ${}^*\!R$ the nonstandard real numbers.

Suppose $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x) = L_1$ in the standard formulation.  That means
$$
(\forall \epsilon \in R, \epsilon>0) (\exists \delta \in R, \delta>0)
(\forall x \in R, 0 < |x-c|<\delta) \big[|f(x)-L_1|<\epsilon\big] .
\tag1$$

We claim the nonstandard formulation holds.  That is,
$$
(\forall x \in {}^*\!R, x-c \text{ infinitesmial})\big[f(x) - L_1\text{ infinitesimal}\big]
\tag2$$
Let $x \in {}^*\!R$ with $x-c$ infinitesimal.  Let $\epsilon \in R, \epsilon > 0$.  By $(1)$ there exists
$\delta > 0, \delta \in R$ as in $(1)$.  But $\delta > 0$ is standard and $x-c$ is infinitesimal, so $|x-c| < \delta$.  Thus we get $|f(x) - L_1| < \epsilon$.
This is true for every standard $\epsilon > 0$, which means
$f(x) -L_1$ is infinitesimal.  This completes the proof of $(2)$.

Converse.  Here is where we use the transfer principle.
Suppose $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L_1$ in the nonstandard formulation.
That is,
$$
(\forall x \in {}^*\!R, x-c \text{ infinitesmial})\big[f(x) - L_1\text{ infinitesimal}\big]
\tag3$$
We claim $(1)$ holds.
Let $\epsilon \in R, \epsilon>0$ be given.  Suppose (for purposes of contradiction) that there is no $\delta>0$ as required in $(1)$.  That means
$$
(\forall \delta \in R, \delta > 0)(\exists x \in R, 0<|x-c|<\delta)
\big[|f(x) - L_1| \ge \epsilon\big]
$$
The transfer principle tells us
$$
(\forall \delta \in {}^*\!R, \delta > 0)(\exists x \in {}^*\!R, 0<|x-c|<\delta)
\big[|f(x) - L_1| \ge \epsilon\big]
\tag4$$
Now let $\delta \in {}^*\!R, \delta > 0$ be infinitesimal.  There is $x \in {}^*\!R, 0 < |x-c| < \delta$ with $|f(x) - L_1| \ge \epsilon$.  Of course this means that $x-c$ is infinitesmial, but $f(x) - L_1$ is not infinitesimal
(recall $\epsilon \in R, \epsilon > 0$).  This contradicts $(3)$.  So: there is, indeed, $\delta>0$ as required in $(1)$.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! What an impressive answer! Thank you!!!  :)

Answer (score 1):

So from definition of $L_1$, for every $\epsilon>0$ we fin dsome $\delta$ such that ...
With the usual constrction via sequences modula an ultrafilter, if $x-c$ is infinitesimal, then "most" (in the sense of the ultrafilter) terms of a sequence representing $x-c$ are absolutely smaller than the corresponding term of the constant $\delta$ sequence. Then for these "most" terms, $f(x)-L_1$ is $<\epsilon$, and as this holds for all positive $\epsilon$, we conclude that $f(x)-L_1$ is infinitesimal.